# Как ограничить числовые значения в инпутах JS?

Tags: javascript

Есть инпут type="number"

```
 <input type="number" min="0" max="2800">
```

Когда вводишь значения стрелками, то ограничение работает. Как теперь сделать, чтобы при вводе числа с клавиатуры, оно автоматически сбрасывалось до максимума или минимума?

Comment: Слшуатель на `input` и смотреть каждый раз на вводимое значение

Comment: А можете в формате кода написать?)

Comment: Не надо это делать. Только пользователя бесить.

Comment: Согласен с @Qwertiy. Лучше проверять при сабмите и показать ошибку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Главное не забываем, что все значения будут строками, так что надо их приводить вручную к типу числа:

```js
const numberInput = document.querySelector('#number');


numberInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
  
  console.log(`'${numberInput.value}' as num is ${Number(numberInput.value)}`);
  
  const value = Number(numberInput.value);
  const max = Number(numberInput.max);
  const min = Number(numberInput.min);
  
  if (value > max) numberInput.value = max;
  else if (value < min) numberInput.value = min;
});
```

```html
<input id="number" type="number" min="0" max="2800">
```

Comment: А что насчёт числен по типу `0xfff` (эквивалент 4095)? Когда я ввожу это число никакой замены не происходит. При этом что странно, если в консоли вписать `Number('0xfff')`, возвращается `4095`, но не понимаю почему число не меняется, ведь вроде по условиям всё должно работать правильно.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Это не строчный инпут, потому он буквенные выражения будет игнорировать. Добавил для вас вывод в консоль, чтобы увидели что приходит на вход

Comment: Большое спасибо! Всё работает